# obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function error in a Firebase database query

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying a cloud function in Firebase that acts as a OAuth2 middleware, handling the authorization and getting the token. After getting the access token and user details I want to store the token and user details in the database and also update or create the user. The code is from [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth). But I'm always getting the same error message from function logs:

```
TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:553:17)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1511:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1528:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1511:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1528:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1511:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1528:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
```

Below is the function for creating a user

```js
async function createFirebaseAccount(uid, displayName, email, accessToken) {
  const databaseTask = admin.database().ref(`/idpAccessToken/${uid}`).set(accessToken);

  const userCreationTask = admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
    displayName: displayName,
    email: email,
    emailVerified: true,
  }).catch((error) => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      return admin.auth().createUser({
        uid: uid,
        displayName: displayName,
        email: email,
        emailVerified: true,
      });
    }
    throw error;
  });

  // execution stops here, when resolving this tasks
  await Promise.all([userCreationTask, databaseTask]);

  const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
  console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
  return token;
}
```

The variables uid, displayName, email and token are a plain text string in all four cases. The token returned from this function is later returned to the calling client using `jsonp`. I don't understand where this error comes from.

Comment: What exactly is the value of accessToken?

Comment: Contains a JWT token

Comment: And the exact value is...?

Comment: The value is this one (some sensitive charater altered) https://pastebin.com/s4aYtcTP

Comment: The error is suggesting that something is not right with Realtime Database, so you have some debugging to do with how you call its APIs.  This doesn't have anything to do with auth.

Comment: Been hours after this and there is no problem with the code above, the problem is that I was not resolving the promise returned by the function `createFirebaseAccount` my bad